# Сохранение изменений в CSV файле

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, обработка-данных

У меня есть файл в расширении csv, в котором хранятся данные о человеке (имя, фамилия, телефон, дата рождения). Мне надо изменить в нем определенную позицию (например, имя). Использую pandas для этого:

```
file = pd.read_csv('phonebook.csv', sep=',')
name = input('Old name: ')
surname = input('Surname: ')
n_name = input('New name: ')
reader = csv.reader(file_obj)

for row in file:
    if name == row[0] and surname == row[1]:
        file.ix[0, row] = n_name

file.to_csv('phonebook.csv', index=False)
```

Однако, после вызова всего файла, изменения не сохраняются. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать так, чтобы изменения сохранились?

Comment: можете привести в вопросе небольшой пример входных и выходных данных? [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вся прелесть Pandas в отсутствии необходимости пользоваться медленными циклами:

```
In [86]: df = pd.read_csv('c:/temp/phonebook.csv')

In [87]: df
Out[87]:
  firstname    lastname
0    George    Gershwin
1    George      Benson
2      Ella  Fitzgerald
3     Louis   Armstrong

In [88]: df.loc[(df['firstname']=='George') & (df['lastname']=='Gershwin'), 'firstname'] = 'Jacob'

In [89]: df
Out[89]:
  firstname    lastname
0     Jacob    Gershwin
1    George      Benson
2      Ella  Fitzgerald
3     Louis   Armstrong

In [90]: df.to_csv('c:/temp/phonebook.csv', index=False)
```